# Database design - Flagged fields

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design

I have an attribute A and therefore a table relating to A:

```
ID  Name   OtherFields  isPrimary
1   foo      stuff          1
2   bar      stuff          0
3   blah     stuff          0
4   blahh    stuff          0
```

The isPrimary column marks a row as primary. Only one row can be primary and there must always be a row set as primary

What is the best way to enforce this at the database level?

Would the best method be to create a new table called Primary which has one column, ID which would be a foreign key which references A.ID?

alternatively, using the table structure outlined above, I know we can enforce no more than one row being set to 1 using a unique index, however I am not sure how can enforce that there must be no less than one row set as 1

I am using MS SQL Server

Comment: It seems to me the first solution (table Primary) is the better both for simplicity as well as efficiency of enforcement, and also for simplicity of programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a new table. I suggest you don't call it PRIMARY because that's a reserved word. You should also include constraints to ensure that it won't have more than one row. Example:

```
CREATE TABLE prm
  (id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES TableA (id),
   IsPrimary BIT NOT NULL
   DEFAULT (1)
   CHECK (IsPrimary=1) UNIQUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Check"

```
CHECK (IsValid(isPrimary) = 'True')
```

and IsValid() like...

```
CREATE FUNCTION IsValid(
    @Tmp VARCHAR(1)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(5)
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table WHERE isPrimary = 1)
        return 'False'
    return 'True'
END
```

Therefore, It can't insert new row which IsPrimary is 0 until all the row's IsPrimary is 0.

Comment: Beware. This CHECK constraint will fail to work the way you expected if more than one row is updated in a single update.